# How to bind data from code behind to a WPF Label, from XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have seen a few similar questions, but none of them dumb it down enough for me.  I've been coding in C# for about two weeks and using WPF for about two days.

I have a class

```
namespace STUFF
{
    public static class Globals
    {
        public static string[] Things= new string[]
        {   
            "First Thing"
        };
    }
}
```

and a window

```
<Window
    x:Class="STUFF.Window1" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:STUFF"
    Title="STUFF"
    Height="600"
    Width="600">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Globals x:Key="globals"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding globals, Path=Things[0]}"/>
</Grid>
```

What is the simplest most dumb downed easy way to bind data from code behind to XAML from within XAML?

This compiles and runs fine, but the label is blank for reasons, obvious I'm sure, which evade me.

Comment: This isn't really code behind. Code behind is defined as the code found in your Window1.xaml.cs file. Each .xaml file has a .xaml.cs code behind file.

Comment: The code behind for Window1 is code defined in the Window1 class?

Comment: Yes, Window1.xaml.cs is the code behind for Window1.xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a `static` `class` you have to mention your source as `x:Static` in `xaml`.

1. Change you field into a property

   ```
   private string[] _Things;

   public string[] Things
   {
       get
       {

           if (_Things == null)
           {
               _Things = new string[] { "First Thing", "Second Thing" };
           }
           return _Things;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Since `Globals` is a static class, you have to bind it using `x:Static`

`<Label Content="{Binding [0], Source={x:Static local:Globals.Things}}"/>`

Comment: Works perfectly.  I can fix it if there are, but out of curiosity are there any potential memory management problems with having a getter return a new array like that?  I use this array a lot, will it be creating completely new, relatively large, arrays every time I call it?  Does it keep the entire array in memory, or just the element I called it for?

Comment: Use a private backing field for the property that initializes the value once. The getter can return the backing field. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: As Lee mentioned use a backing field. I have updated my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues.

1. You can only bind to properties, not fields. Change the Things definition to

   ```
   private readonly static string[] _things = new string[] { "First Thing" };
   public static string[] Things { get { return _things; } }
   ```
2. The binding should list global as a source. Change the binding to this

   ```
   <Label Content="{Binding Path=Things[0], Source={StaticResource globals}}"/>
   ```

Comment: 'The invocation of the constructor on type STUFF.Globals' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '12' and line position '4'. ---> System.ArgumentException: Array may not be empty.'  Do you know why it would tell me this?

Comment: I either had to make this a non-static class to work with the StaticResource and key like you had up above. Or get rid of the Resources section and bind directly to the static class like Anand did in his answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I chose the other answer because I would need to rewrite a lot of stuff to make this non static.

Comment: No worries. Just glad I could help!